# Wallet support for assets minted on AssetHub

Tags: wallet, assethub

Is there any wallet that is able to display assets minted on the Polkadot AssetHub (other than polkadot.js/apps)? The only wallet I've found that displays some AssetHub assets is NovaWallet, but the support seems to be limited to significant assets (namely USDC, USDT).